# What does smooth scroll function do?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

Can someone explain me what does this function

```
$('a').click(function(){
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $( $(this).attr('href') ).offset().top
}, 500);
return false;});
```

do in this line?

```
scrollTop: $( $(this).attr('href') ).offset().top
```

Comment: sets `scrollTop` prorerty = `$( $(this).attr('href') ).offset().top` coordinate

Comment: Did you try checking the documentation for an explanation? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop

Comment: Yes but I don't understand how this line sets scrolltop property adding or subtracting every time some pixels to do the scroll...